# Lining up spaced columns with column above

Tags: css

Is it possible to line up the second column(green box) with the grey box above whilst keeping equal spacing between the columns.

I know you can just remove the white space but I'm wanting them to have padding.

Maybe some way with the calc function?

https://jsfiddle.net/g76qzwy2/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  color: #fff;
}
/* Top left & right col */

.left-col {
  background: grey;
  float: left;
  width: 66.6%;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.right-col {
  background: orange;
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  padding: 1rem;
}
/* Col row */

.col-row {
  margin-left: -1rem;
}
/* Bottom cols */

.col {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
}
.col-a,
.col-b,
.col-c {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
/* Col content */

.col-a-content {
  background: red;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.col-b-content {
  background: green;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.col-c-content {
  background: blue;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="left-col">
    <span>test content</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right-col">
    <span>test content</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-row">
    <div class="col col-a">
      <div class="col-a-content">
        <span>col a</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-b">
      <div class="col-b-content">
        <span>col a</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-c">
      <div class="col-c-content">
        <span>col a</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  color: #fff;
}
/* Top left & right col */

.left-col {
  background: grey;
  float: left;
  width: calc(66.6% - .333rem);
  padding: 1rem;
}
.right-col {
  background: orange;
  float: right;
  width: calc(33.3% - .666rem);
  padding: 1rem;
}
/* Col row */

.col-row {
  margin-left: -1rem;
}
/* Bottom cols */

.col {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
}
.col-a,
.col-b,
.col-c {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
/* Col content */

.col-a-content {
  background: red;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.col-b-content {
  background: green;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.col-c-content {
  background: blue;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="left-col">
    <span>test content</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right-col">
    <span>test content</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-row">
    <div class="col col-a">
      <div class="col-a-content">
        <span>col a</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-b">
      <div class="col-b-content">
        <span>col a</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-c">
      <div class="col-c-content">
        <span>col a</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the calc function to calculate the space you need. You only need a small amount of extra spacing (`.66rem`) which is calculated the same as the width of the bigger element.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  color: #fff;
}
/* Top left & right col */

.left-col {
  background: grey;
  float: left;
  width: calc(66.66% + .66rem);
  padding: 1rem;
}
.right-col {
  background: orange;
  float: left;
  width: calc(33.3% - .66rem);
  padding: 1rem;
}
/* Col row */

.col-row {
  margin-left: -1rem;
}
/* Bottom cols */

.col {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
}
.col-a,
.col-b,
.col-c {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
/* Col content */

.col-a-content {
  background: red;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.col-b-content {
  background: green;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.col-c-content {
  background: blue;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="left-col">
    <span>test content</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right-col">
    <span>test content</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-row">
    <div class="col col-a">
      <div class="col-a-content">
        <span>col a</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-b">
      <div class="col-b-content">
        <span>col a</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-c">
      <div class="col-c-content">
        <span>col a</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```